# Can't figure out why my Bitbucket Cloud doesn't work

Tags: git, bitbucket

I uploaded a complete project to my bitbucket repository, but when I go to 'accountname'.bitbucket.io it says 'Repository not found'. I'm sure I pushed all the files to my repository and I'm sure I use the right url format. Now I created a new account with just a single index.html file but I still can't fix the problem. Can you tell me please what am I doing wrong https://noideanoidea.bitbucket.io./ ? You can see my repository here https://bitbucket.org/noideanodiea/noideanodiea.bitbucket.io./src/master 
So what I've done is: created a bitbucket account > created a repository with the same name as my account name+bitbucket.io. at the end > cloned the repository to my pc > created an html file > added it + committed + pushed. File is in the repository but Cloud hosting doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your repository is named `noideanodiea.bitbucket.io.`, not `noideanodiea.bitbucket.io` (notice the trailing `.`).

[BitBucket's documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud-221449776.html) is a little confusing since some references to the repo name are at the end of a period, but other sentences make this clearer:

> Your repository name would be happycat.bitbucket.io and the published static website is reached by this URL: https://happycat.bitbucket.io

I left feedback on the site suggesting clarifying the examples, click the "Provide feedback about this article" link at the bottom of the page if you'd like to as well.